# Getting date range from Google API Reporting Object?

Tags: php, google-api, google-reporting-api

I am using the v4 version of the reporting API and have a function which builds the report I want. The only thing problem I am facing is finding a way to get the dates reported on from within another function.

```
function getReport($analytics, $start_date, $end_date) {

            // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
            $VIEW_ID = "XXXXXXX";

            // Create the DateRange object.
            $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
            $dateRange->setStartDate("$start_date");
            $dateRange->setEndDate("$end_date");

            // Create the Metrics object.
            $transactionRevenue = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
            $transactionRevenue->setExpression("ga:transactionRevenue");
            $transactionRevenue->setAlias("Revenue");

            $transID = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
            $transID->setName('ga:transactionId');
            $campaign = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
            $campaign->setName('ga:campaign');
            $date = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
            $date->setName('ga:date');

            $camFil = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilter();
            $camFil->setDimensionName('ga:campaign');
            $camFil->setExpressions(array('.*[^0-9].*'));
            $camFil->setOperator('REGEXP');

            $dimensionFilterClause = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DimensionFilterClause();
            $dimensionFilterClause->setOperator('AND');
            $dimensionFilterClause->setFilters(array($camFil));

            // Create the ReportRequest object.
            $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
            $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
            $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
            $request->setMetrics(array($transactionRevenue));
            $request->setDimensions(array($date, $transID, $campaign, $medium, $source));
            $request->setSamplingLevel('LARGE');
            $request->setDimensionFilterClauses($dimensionFilterClause);
            $request->setPageSize(10000);

            $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
            $body->setReportRequests( array($request) );
            return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
        }
```

At the moment I pass the start date and end date again so I can break down the date range if the result is sampled. The issue with passing the date is the function below then has to be changed whenever I want to pass a new parameter into getReport.

```
getFullResults( $analytics, $start_date, $end_date );
```

Anyone else used the GA Reporting API and seen if they store the date in the results? The only thing I've found is the min and max but not sure the format to use it.

```
     ["minimums"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["values"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(3) "0.0"
          }
        }
      }
      ["maximums"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["values"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(8) "48780.59"
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Are you using this API? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Comment: Yeah that is the one, had a read through and could not find the answer in the docs.